# In C++, why are my variable inputs that are separated by a space being stored incorrectly?

Tags: c++, variables, input, char, integer

In this code I ask the user for inputs separated by a space, gradeOne space gradeTwo.
However, it is not functioning as intended so I added output statements at the end to see if the values were stored correctly.

If I type in: 59 95 gradeOne should be 59, temp should be ' ' and gradeTwo should be 95 but the output says gradeOne is 59, temp is 9 and gradeTwo is 5. What is happening? Thank you for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int gradeOne, gradeTwo;
    char temp;
    cout<<"Please enter 2 grades, separated by a space: ";
    cin>>gradeOne>>temp>>gradeTwo;
    
    if(gradeOne < 60 && gradeTwo < 60)
        cout<<"Student Failed:("<<endl;
    else if(gradeOne >= 95 && gradeTwo >= 95)
        cout<<"Student Graduated with Honors:)"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Student Graduated!"<<endl;
    
    cout<<gradeOne<<endl;
    cout<<gradeTwo<<endl;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

operator >> automatically skip space. Just change to:

```
cin>>gradeOne>>gradeTwo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the char variable. I removed it and the below worked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gradeOne, gradeTwo;

    cout << "Please enter 2 grades";
    cin >> gradeOne >> gradeTwo;

    if (gradeOne < 60 && gradeTwo < 60)
        cout << "Student Failed:(" << endl;
    else if (gradeOne >= 95 && gradeTwo >= 95)
        cout << "Student Graduated with Honors:)" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Student Graduated!" << endl;

    cout << gradeOne << endl;
    cout << gradeTwo << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Are you wanting to use the char variable for a specific reason?

Comment: No, I'm new to c++ and thought the space needed to be defined so the compiler would know the difference between gradeOne and gradeTwo